# Force image download with htaccess

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, hotlinking

With the following code I can replace the hotlinked image with another image. However, is it possible to force download the **replaced image** instead of opening in the browser?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(subdomain\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i.imgur.com/D5ZIJBq.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758866/257319

Answer (score 2):

You can not force download with this rewrite.

Your server must serve this file (for example in http://subdomain.mydomain.com//img/my_fake_image.jpg). 
Then, modify you rewrite rule and add the following rule (not tested and to adapt)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(subdomain\.)?mydomain.com.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://subdomain.mydomain.com/img/my_fake_image.jpg [NC,R,L]
<FilesMatch "\.my_fake_image.jpg$">
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please explain it a bit, what you mean not to adapt? will it harm? Should I place your code below the rewrite rule, will it only force download the imgur.com image? Thanks.

Comment: it does not work, it still displays in the browser, headers mode is enabled in apache, so there is no problem with that.